# Using the recursive function by making the type transformation in the generic method at run time

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, reflection

I have a list from AppLayerGroup class, within this list I have another list from AppLayer class. What I want to do is to translate each property of the list I send to the TranslateList method into a language of my choice. If the corresponding value of each property of the list exists in the view, I update it. If the property is a list, I try to send the new list back to the Translate method with the help of the recursive function. But type 'T' is not same as first time type, I need to convert it at runtime but I don't know how to do that.

```
    public class AppLayer : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AppLayerGroupId { get; set; }
        public string LayerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppLayerGroup : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GroupKey { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppLayer> AppLayer { get; set; }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> TranslateList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        var _httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.EndsWith("nameidentifier"))?.Value;
        var _cacheManager = (ICacheManager)ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ICacheManager));

        short appLangId = Convert.ToInt16(_cacheManager.Get($"{CacheKeys.UserLang}={userId}"));

        Translate(data, appLangId);

        return data;
    }

    

    public static IEnumerable<T> Translate<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, short appLangId)
    {
        string classname = (data.FirstOrDefault() as Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor).DynProxyGetTarget().GetType().BaseType.Name;

        var _vAppLookupLanguageRepository = (IVAppLookupLanguageRepository)ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IVAppLookupLanguageRepository));
        var langList = _vAppLookupLanguageRepository.GetList(a => a.EntityName == classname && a.AppLanguageId == appLangId);

        if (langList.IsAny() && data.IsAny())
        {
            foreach (var item in data )
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IEnumerable").Name == "IEnumerable")
                    {
                        var subList = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(item, null);

                        Translate((IEnumerable<T>)subList, 2); //I should submit the type of subList instead of 'T'
                    }
                    if (langList.Any(a => a.ColumnName == prop.Name))
                        prop.SetValue(item, langList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UniqueValue == prop.GetValue(item).ToString()).LanguageValue, null);
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

[image]

When I query the AppLayerGroup, the AppLayerGroup list will return by localizing the properties inside each list element. I expect it to perform the same operations and localize it in the AppLayer list under the AppLayerGroup list.

I did some research but couldn't find the right result.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm trying to translate each list property. I am using T to be able to send to recursive function. do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: My bad, I somehow understand it as localization. Ignore my comment.

Comment: This looks like your application requires globalization and localization. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielDearlove actually trying to make localization exactly.

Comment: @omerfarukaktas if you are localizing, are you already following the [Globalization and Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) advice? Also, I am still trying to work out why you must use reflection and not make `Translate()` methods for your specific classes?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. So, for an `AppLayer` class, you want to update the contents of the `LayerName` property. First, you select the records where EntityName is "AppLayer", the known AppLanguageId from the cache manager, ColumnName is "LayerName" and the UniqueName is the contents of existing object. Then, you want to substitute the contents of `LayerName` with the value in the LanguageValue. Have I got that correct? For `AppLayerGroup`, you want to do something similar for the `GroupKey` property and all items in the 'AppLayer' collection. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielDearlove yes i am trying to do exactly that

Comment: @Sinatr yes, i am trying to do localization thank you for your interest

Comment: If it's localization, then *"localizing the properties inside each list element"* doesn't make sense as well as generics. You should only translate strings. The storage of strings has to be specialized in storing strings and you only need to translate those strings. Did I mentioned it has to be strings?

Comment: @Sinatr i am thinking of localizing only strings, i will save only string names that i want to localize in database, when a list is requested it will check if string name is in database, if there is it will localize

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to translate fields in a handful of classes, `AppLayer` and `AppLayerGroup` in your example, directly implementing the translations and avoiding reflection is probably the better option:

```
/// <summary>
/// Translates the string fields from the base language to a target language
/// </summary>
public static AppLayer Translate(AppLayer input, short appLangId)
{
    string classname = input.GetType().Name;
    var _vAppLookupLanguageRepository = (IVAppLookupLanguageRepository)ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IVAppLookupLanguageRepository));
    var langList = _vAppLookupLanguageRepository.GetList(
        a => a.EntityName == classname && 
             a.AppLanguageId == appLangId &&
             a.ColumnName == "LayerName");

    string newLayerName = langList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UniqueValue == input.LayerName).LanguageValue, null);

    return new AppLayer
    {
        Id = input.Id,
        AppLayerGroupId = input.AppLayerGroupId,
        LayerName = newLayerName
    };
}
```

I have just bashed this out at the keyboard so it will not be precisely correct. If you refactor to a common `private static` translation lookup function where you pass in the language repository as a parameter then you can handle the `AppLayerGroup` properties in the same way as for `AppLayer`. You can just iterate over the `AppLayerGroup.AppLayer` collection.

Comment: AppLayerGroup was just a small example, there are so many classes like this in the project that I need to localize, it doesn't make much sense to me to write different methods for all of them, and it would take a lot of time.

Comment: That is what I expected. In a deployed application, I doubt you can apply [Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) yet so that leaves reflection. I suggest you have some test cases set up with the most complex data types you need to convert as a minimum. Also, it might be worth adding a class attribute to identify types that can be translated and you throw an exception for types that should not be translated.